# Creating a directory with strings of arrays as the name

Tags: python, arrays, string

I simply need to create a directory in python using

```
os.system('mkdir ' + sub_dir)
```

with

```
sub_dir = ('x_y_prior=' + str(not use_est_centroid) +
          '_randomized_x_y=' + str(randomize) +
          '_sep=' + str(separation) +
          '_num_trial_arr=' + str(num_trial_arr) + 
          '_seed_arr=' + str(seed_arr) +
          '_image_params=' + str(image_params) + 
          '_obj_a_info=' + str(obj_a) +
          '_obj_b_info=' + str(obj_a))
```

The variables consist of arrays. Now the problem is that when I attempt this, the command creates many directories with the individual elements of the each array as a name.

For example, if

```
separation = [1.2,1.4]
```

then I will get two directories named

```
1.2/
```

and

```
1.4/
```

I simply want one directory with the name of the entire string above.

Comment: What? Can you provide example of output directory name or structure?

Comment: You can trying join() for converting the list to string before passing. Is there any specific reason to use os.system instead of os.mkdir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a directory in Python, you are asking the command shell to execute the command `mkdir` to create a directory. Now the problem is that the command shell can interpret some characters as meta characters - for example I am using the `zsh` shell on linux, if I execute:

```
os.system("mkdir foo{1.2,1.4}bar")
```

(not `[` but `{` there), I will end up with 2 directories: `foo1.2bar` and `foo1.4bar`, because that is how `{a,b,c}` behaves on `zsh`.

---

Now the solution of course is to use *python* to create this directory:

```
os.mkdir("foo{1.2,1.4}bar")
```

And we end up with having a directory named `foo{1.2,1.4}bar`.

---

Thus in your case, do

```
os.mkdir(sub_dir)
```